# Building non-console Windows app with Qt and cmake

Tags: qt, visual-c++, cmake

I am having trouble finding out the current up-to-date method for building non-console apps using cmake, Qt5 and Visual C++ under Windows. It looks like back in the Qt4 days it was sufficient to set QT_USE_QTMAIN to true. Now supposedly it's sufficient to link Qt5::WinMain. However, neither of these is working for me - my app continues to open a console window. I also cannot find anything in either the cmake or the Qt documentation.

What's the documented/proven method to get the app to stop opening a console window?

Comment: You might need to call the following to deactive the console `set_target_properties(<targename> PROPERTIES WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE)`

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Perhaps you can reply to my question as an actual answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `set_target_properties(<targetname> PROPERTIES WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE)` to your executable target in `CMakeLists.txt` to let CMake generate the executable for windows without a console. This replaces the `main` entry point of the application with `WinMain`.